# Wait for my files to be created. JS (express-fileupload)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Express-fileupload has a function that allows to move the .mv() file, what I am looking for is to wait for it to finish so I can proceed with the next task.

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

**CODE**

```
console.log("Starting the loop")
for (const element of _sources) {
  const file = req.files[element];
  if (file !== undefined) {
    const _mime = mimesList.filter((v) => v.mimetype === file.mimetype);
    if (_mime.length === 0) {
      //... exec
    } else {
      console.log("Start moving the file")
      const previewPath = _path + new tokenGenerator().generate() + element + _mime[0].extension;
      await file.mv(previewPath, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          //!make error
        }
        req.files[element].preview = previewPath;
        console.log("No errors")
      });
      console.log("I have finished moving the file.")
    }
  } else {
    //.. exec
  }
}
console.log("Ending the loop")
```

**current output**

```
Starting the loop
Start moving the file
I have finished moving the file.
Start moving the file
I have finished moving the file.
Start moving the file
I have finished moving the file.
Ending the loop
No errors
No errors
No errors
```

**expected output**

```
Starting the loop
Start moving the file
No errors
I have finished moving the file.
Start moving the file
No errors
I have finished moving the file.
Start moving the file
No errors
I have finished moving the file.
Ending the loop
```

Comment: You don't need to `await file.mv()`. It is not a promise. It already has a callback

Comment: Also, `for of` loop directly gives you element of array. You don't need to do this `const file = req.files[element];`.

Comment: @Inder the element is used because I manage a separate array, e.g. files.previewSaveSpecified(["logo", "test", "test1"]),

Comment: I forgot that having a callback makes it asynchronous, I will now create a promise to make it asynchronous/await, thank you very much.